# mmap and munmap behaviour

Tags: c, posix, mmap

The Open Group standard says that munmap should be called with a page aligned address, but there doesn't seem to be any requirement that mmap should be returning a page aligned address. Is this something you need to handle when you're writing portable code?

Comment: I think you can pretty much assume that the address returned by `mmap` is suitably aligned, I think that the `munmap` requirement is there in case you are calculating a subset of a previously map range to unmap. I can't find any evidence to support my assertion though.

Comment: Somewhere (in the definition of `PAGE_SIZE` perhaps?) POSIX mentions that an implementation can (and presumably should) define the page size as 1 if there is no alignment restriction.

Comment: You should read the full documentation for mmap -- see my response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmap will only map whole pages, and can thus only return a page boundary. It's in the short description:

mmap - map **pages** of memory

(emphasis mine)

Comment: You would think they could mention it in the body though.

Answer (score 1):

mmap documentation does mention this requirement, although in an off-handed manner.  on my mac, for example:

```
     [EINVAL]           The offset argument was not page-aligned based on the
                        page size as returned by getpagesize(3).
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html also says

[EINVAL]  The addr argument (if MAP_FIXED was specified) or off is not a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(), or is considered invalid by the implementation.

Comment: I don't see how this translates to a requirement that mmap should always return page aligned addresses. It only specifies a requirement on a specific argument. You could probably assume that the address returned by mmap is page aligned, but when you want to write portable code I think it's better to be sure.

Comment: @onemasse there are more constraints there -- read the entire discussion and the EINVAL error conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the most natural arrangement (that is, when both the physical and virtual addresses have the same page granularity and alignment). The whole purpose of page translation is to break the virtual address space into spans and independently map them onto blocks of physical memory (pages), with 1 span covering exactly 1 block (page). Even with pages of mixed sizes, the alignment is naturally preserved (e.g. regular page=4KB and large page=2GB/4GB on x86/64; [some illustrations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Page_table_structures)).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly, if MAP_FIXED is not specified, the behavior of mmap is implementation dependent. So the only portable way of using mmap is with MAP_FIXED, which means you have to provide an address that is page aligned. Otherwise you'll receive EINVAL.

Comment: This is in fact exactly backward: to use `MAP_FIXED` you have to know the address space layout.  Without `MAP_FIXED` you don't know *where* the OS is going to put your memory map, but you shouldn't *need* to know that, same way you don't need to know where `malloc` is going to put your next allocation.

Comment: But if I don't specify MAP_FIXED the implementation is free to use the addr argument as it choses, and there's no requirement that the memory returned should be page aligned. So I need to check that the address returned is page aligned before I do munmap on it?

Comment: No, you can assume the address is page aligned.  If the standards don't require the address returned by `mmap` (when successful) to be an acceptable argument to `munmap`, that is an oversight and not something you actually have to worry about.